# Can I append a string with the ng-include URL?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-include

Can I do something like this :

`<div ng-include="{{data}}Template"></div>`
 -- Requirement is to append a constant string with the template URL.

Answer (score 3):

yes you can do it like this,

```
<div ng-include="data+'Template' "></div>
```