# How to perform concatination in a template in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, templates, angularjs-ng-include

I have a template which I need to show the path of a template dynamically.

```
<div data-ng-include="'app/templates/'templateUrl'.html'"></div>

$scope.templateUrl = "text";
```

But the link is not mapped as :

```
app/templates/text.html
```

Can any one please help me. Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I append a string with the ng-include URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20755200/can-i-append-a-string-with-the-ng-include-url)

Answer (score 1):

Try this way. Make a string by concatenating the parts.

```
<div data-ng-include="'app/templates/' + {{ templateUrl }} + '.html'"></div>
```